# C++ partial template specialization: how to specialize std::iterator_category

Tags: c++, template-specialization, partial-specialization

I want to write template function void foo() which takes 2 iterators or pointers.

I want to have a specialized version for random_access_iterator. I try to write like below:

```
// generic version
template<class Iter, typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category>
void foo(Iter first, Iter last);

// Specialized version for random_access_iterator
template<class RandomIter>
void foo<RandomIter, std::random_access_iterator_tag>(RandomIter first, RandomIter last)
{
}
```

It gives error: **illegal use of explicit template arguments**

Please let me know what is correct way of defining this. Thanks

Comment: The standard way of doing this is "tag dispatching". I can write up an answer based on it tomorrow if needed but Google should tell you what you need.

Comment: @John5342 I've searched "tag dispatching" and got the idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on "tag dispatching" pattern, I've written a solution to my question:

```
// Using "= delete" on un-supported categories to get concise compile-time error information
template<typename Iter> void _foo(Iter first, Iter last, std::bidirectional_iterator_tag) = delete;

template<typename RandomIter>
void _foo(RandomIter first, RandomIter last, std::random_access_iterator_tag)
{ ... }

template<class Iter>
void foo(Iter first, Iter last)
{
    typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category category;
    _foo(first, last, category);
}
```

It works now. Please leave comment if it has bug or need improvement. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can't partially specialize function templates. Partial specialization is only available to class templates. What you can do is to have just one function template which delegates to `static` members of suitably specialized class templates, e.g.

```
template <typename Iter,
          typename = typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category>
struct foo_impl {
    static void call(Iter first, Iter last);
};

template <typename Iter>
struct foo_impl<Iter, std::random_acces_iterator_tag> {
    static void call(Iter first, Iter last);
};

templlate <typename Iter>
void foo(Iter first, last) {
    foo_impl<Iter>::call(first, last);
}
```

Alternatively you can use partial ordering. In that case there are two function templates one taking a general iterator category as argument and another one taking a specific category as argument. The category or a pointer to it is passed as additional argument. I think this requires a forwarding function, too (I'm normally using the approach using partial specializations of a class template).

Answer (score 1):

As a complement of previous answers with ways to achieve the same result using newer C++ standard versions.

### C++17

You can use [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if):

```cpp
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

template<class Iter>
void foo(Iter first, Iter last)
{
    using Cat = typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category;
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Cat, std::random_access_iterator_tag>) {
        // random access iterator
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Cat, std::bidirectional_iterator_tag>) {
        // bidirectional iterator
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Cat, std::forward_iterator_tag>) {
        // forward iterator
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Cat, std::input_iterator_tag>) {
        // input iterator
    }
}
```

### C++20

You can overload the function and discriminate between each case using [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints):

```cpp
#include <iterator>

template<std::random_access_iterator Iter>
void foo(Iter first, Iter last)
{
    // random access iterator
}

template<std::bidirectional_iterator Iter>
void foo(Iter first, Iter last)
{
    // bidirectional iterator
}

template<std::forward_iterator Iter>
void foo(Iter first, Iter last)
{
    // forward iterator
}

template<std::input_iterator Iter>
void foo(Iter first, Iter last)
{
    // input iterator
}
```